# Replace " " character in an NSString with "\ " (to create a Unix path)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Using the following doesn't work:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

By doesn't work I mean does not do any replacement what so ever. It returns the same exact string.

Is there a convenience method to do this? Similar to:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

My code (just one line):

```
NSString *escapedPath = [pathToBeConverted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                                                     withString:@"\ "];
```

Also, my compiler warning. Which likely has much to do with this:

```
warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Why doesn't -stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: work?

Comment: I mean it does no replacement what so ever

Comment: It should work. Show us your code.

Comment: code added. (but just one line)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `@"\\ "` instead of `@"\ "`. In C `\` is the escape character. You need to escape it with another `\`.

Comment: Thanks. that was dumb, I was dumping into an NSAppleScript, which was also escaped and I completely missed it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is exactly what I need. I need to get rid of spaces in the file names

Comment: Oh, got it. I was thinking you have a space delimited string and you want to construct a path name with it.