# Escape character in NSString

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa-touch, postgresql, sanitization

I have encounter a problem. I have a NSString and I would like to send this string to server to insert to database. But I have problem when NSString is (for example):

> This isn't a student.

And this string is sent to server side with this script:

```
$value = $_POST["stringvalue"]

insert into stringtable (stringvalue) values ('$value');
```

Because of "`isn't`" part, the insert query can not run and fail.

Now I would like to escape characters, that means "`isn't`" will become "`isn\'t`" so that I can insert to database. I would like to ask how can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on input sanitation methods, it is best to insert data using *only* parameterised statements. Learn more about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) and more specifically how to avoid it [in PHP](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

One particular problem with input sanitation is that you must do it before every insert, and sometimes it may be done twice accidentally, and so on. Simply used parameterised statements and it will be easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

[Replace " " character in an NSString with "\ " (to create a Unix path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556979/replace-character-in-an-nsstring-with-to-create-a-unix-path)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a problem of PHP instead of iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these PHP methods on the server side :

```
$value = addslashes($_POST["stringvalue"]);
```

To add slashes on your `$value` ([addslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php))

```
$value = html_special_chars($_POST["stringvalue"]);
```

To escape all special chars. [addslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

It's not an iPhone problem I think.